# How do I implement cross-domain tracking between GA4 and DotDigital form tracking?

Tags: cross-domain, google-tag-manager, tracking, google-analytics-4

For context, we work with a client who uses embedded DotDigital forms on their landing pages in order to track enquiries.

These DotDigital forms not only send the collected data to their DotDigital account, but also has it's own GA4 property where we are in theory able to see the number of form submissions. We did this by setting up a custom event in GTM.

However, due to the form being embedded onsite, all traffic is currently being grouped as referral or direct, meaning we can't fully attribute conversions against our campaign UTM's.

Is this a cross-domain tracking problem causing the traffic to group this way? If so, how do we fix it? We've implemented the GA4 tracking code into the DotDigital form already.

Thanks for anyone who can help on this - it's driving me crazy!